# disconnect event in tornado long polling chat

Tags: chat, tornado, long-polling

I am working on a chat application which uses Tornado at backend. I have used long polling to fetch the number of online users and the any new chat message available at server. I have opened two long polling connections with the server.

While it is very easily to detect when a user came online. 
I have coded this class which maintains a list(user) of users who came online.
This list is easily sent to any client requesting for online users(as you can see in the code below.) 
But when a user goes offline, I have no way to know that and hence the list (user) sill remains the same. So even if somebody goes offline I cannot update the user list.
Please help me figure out a way to by which I can remove the user which are not connected (using long polling) and update the user list.
I have heard that I have to apply certain kind of polling mechanism on the list user, as a disconnect event is not generated in tornado, unlike node.js. 
    Please help me implement that polling mechanism. Response in code would be highly appreciated.

```
class OnlineHandler(BaseHandler):
    online = [] 
    identifier = [] 
    user = []
    time = []
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        random = self.get_argument("random", None)
        self.online_user(self.get_current_user(), self.retuser,random)

    def online_user(self, u, callback, random):
        cls = OnlineHandler
        if u not in cls.user:    
       cls.time.append(time.time())
       cls.user.append(u)
    else:
           index = cls.user.index(u)    
       cls.time[index] = time.time()            
        cls.online.append(callback)
        if random not in cls.identifier:                # new user connected
           cls.identifier.append(random)
           logging.info("Sending online list to %r users",len(cls.online))
           for callback in cls.online:
               try:
                   callback(cls.user)
               except:
                   logging.error("Error in online user callback", exc_info=True)
           cls.online = []
```

Answer (score 1):

### I couldn't see where you remove your cls.user. The following is my long polling code:

class LongPollingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     @tornado.web.asynchronous
     def get(self):
          global online, count  ,lastcount
          self.connection_closed = False
          self.user = self.get_argument("name", None)
          if self.user not in online:
               logging.info("user : " + self.user)
               online.append(self.user)
          http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
          appURL = self.request.protocol + "://" + self.request.host
          http.fetch(appURL + "/internal-polling", self._on_finish)

```
 '''push to the client'''  
 def _on_finish(self, response):
      global online, count  ,ipollcount
      gone = self.request.connection.stream.closed()
      print (self.user +" => " + str(gone))
      if gone:
           online.remove(self.user)
           return
      self.write("welcome %s, current online number(s) %s" % (self.user, response.body))
```

### self.finish()

But I just got your problem on openshift's hosting(it's ok on my localhost when client is gone), I don't know if the tornado is behind the proxy,will the proxy cut connection following the client. I'm seeking the answer too.